# How to write a Java program to open a specific file extension (.pef)?

Tags: java

I need to write a java program to open a specific file extension (This is to open a `.pef` file). This java program is being written to open this `.pef` file and print it. But I don't know how to write a program that can open the `.pef` file extension by default.

Comment: So you have already written code to open a specific file, right?  Like `abc.pef`?  And you need help adding the `.pef` extension to the basename?

Comment: I don't understand why this was down voted. Seems to me a very valid question.

Comment: Are you asking about setting file associations so when you click on a file it automatically opens in your java program?

Comment: @MonsterTruck - the problem is that the question is unclear.  It is hard to know what is *actually* being asked.  And the answers reflect this lack of clarity.  In short, it *is* worthy of down-votes.

Comment: @StephenC Fair enough. I agree.

Comment: @Norm - Yes. I need to open pef type from my exe (exe created using jar)

Answer (score 1):

#### This solution is Windows specific

In this post I am assuming that your program is already capable of reading files of type .pef and printing them. If not then please refer to Treebranch's and Himanshu's posts here to figure out how to do so. Next I will assume that your program is to be invoked on the Windows command line as:

```
program.exe <filename.pef>
```

To programatically change the association, follow these steps:

#### Define a file type

```
ftype peffile="program.exe" "%1"
```

Remember to use the absolute path of `program.exe` here.

#### Associate this file type with .pef

```
assoc .pef=peffile
```

Comment: How does that do 'print'?  Is it cross-platform?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I assumed that the program is already capable of opening the .pef file and printing it and that the author was asking to associate files of .pef type with that program. If not, then this question is very general --we need to define "reading" and "printing" as concrete problems.

Comment: @AndrewThompson As you are editing the question, may I suggest that we add an operating system and define the problem more clearly? We should define how the file is to be read, interpreted, and printed (spreadsheet, text, image) etc.

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) *Launches the associated application to open the file.*
- [`Desktop.edit(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit%28java.io.File%29) *Launches the associated editor application and opens a file for editing.*
- [`Desktop.print(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#print%28java.io.File%29) ***Prints a file with the native desktop printing facility, using the associated application's print command.***

This presumes the application has already been associated with the file-type.  To create the file association, launch your app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & declare the file type in the launch file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this file type, but I am guessing you are going to have to read the bytes of the file and then go from there. You should be able to use a `FileInputStream`. Try looking at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileInputStream to read a file.

```
FileInputStream fr=new FileInputStream("xyz.pef");
int i=0;
while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
   System.out.print((char)i);
fr.close();
```